# Import dart file in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, import

I'm working on a flutter project and I want to import a dart file in my main file but I don't know how to do it.
I import my dart file first `import 'package:splash/Categories.dart';`
and I initialized it like that `final Category _category = Category();`
but I have this error `Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports`
Please how can I fix it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the same class is in two different files. So if you want to use a specific class in specific file we need to use aliases.

Example:

```
import 'package:splash/Categories.dart';
import 'package:something/Something.dart' as name;
```

Use classname in `Something.dart` as **name.class_name**